# Entity Framework creates a plural table name, but the view expects a singular table name?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MySQL .net connector 6.4.4.0 and Entity Frame work 4.1 and trying to create the most basic of code-first implementations.

```
public class myDB: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}
```

my model

```
public class Vote
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

my home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    myDB_db = new myDB();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Votes;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

my strongly typed view (using List scaffold)

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.Vote>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
```

It creates the table 'votes' in mySQL with all the right properties.

However, it throws at this line:

@foreach (var item in Model)

with the exception:

**"Table 'mydb.vote' doesn't exist"**

edit: 
To clarify, I actually want table pluralization, and it seems to properly create the table.  I'm hoping to discover the reason for the singular/plural discrepancy.  None of the tutorials and videos from microsoft / Plural Sight / scott gu handle using mysql, so i have to imagine that the .netconnector might be the culprit.  I would also like to avoid using the [Table("Votes")] attributes.  Basically I'm hoping for as much of an 'out of the box' solution as possible.

edit2 (some more relevant code):
when i remove this...tables fail to create all together.
but the view throws an exception looking for 'votes' not 'vote'.
within global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myDB>());

     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public class myDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myDB>
{
    protected override void Seed(myDBcontext)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does using the `Table` attribute solve the problem? You could also use the fluent API if you don't like the attribute. Have you tried it with SQL Express? Maybe there is a problem with the MySQL connector

Comment: i actually just tried adding [Table("Votes")] above the Vote class, and the problem persists.  and no, i havent tried with SQLExpress because i need to make it work with mysql :-)

Comment: ps.  making the table attribute have the value of Vote, fixes the problem.  Why does the view expect the wrong table name!!?? :(

Comment: I don't know MySQL at all, so I can only ask if you are 100% sure that the table in MySQL is named 'votes' and not 'vote'

Comment: yep, just logged into the server and checked out the db.  definitely named 'votes'.

Comment: @cwyers: If it isn't too late, I've heard from our local DBA and read that it is good DB practice to keep table names singular.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So I gave up on trying to do it the way I felt it should be done and removed pluralization all together.  I don't really know for certain, but I assume the problem has to do with the mysql .net connector's support of EF.  Here is what I did.

First, there was a bug in my ApplicationStart method:

```
//WRONG
//Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myDB>());
Database.SetInitializer(new myDBInitializer());
```

Second, I stopped calling the OnModelCreating base implementation which is not listed in the original code since I only implemented it as per jgauffin's suggestion:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //DONT DO THIS ANYMORE
    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().ToTable("Votes")
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Third, I read in some posts that the MySQL .net Connector doesn't let EF actually CREATE a database, so I had initially created the blank DB.  This seems to no longer be the case with connector 6.4.4+, and as long as your connection string's user has the ability to create new databases, it works better if one is not existing initially.

Once, I did all of the above, it seemed to work.  So now I can at least move forward.  Hopefully we can figure out the cause of the plural / singular discrepancy in the future.

Thanks to everyone for their time and effort.

Comment: Thanks this helped me. In case someone gets the following error: `Can't create table 'yourdb.#sql-440_4fa8' (errno: 150)`, it means you forgot to remove the `TableAttribute` on one of your models (error 150 is foreign key related).

Answer (score 23):

In your myDB context class, override the following method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

to have it not pluralize the generated table names.

Comment: Oh, you actually want the plural table names. The above is not likely to help in that case. The described behavior sounds like a bug in the MySQL EF provider.

Comment: Here's a longer explanation of the post by Morten. http://edspencer.me.uk/2012/03/13/entity-framework-plural-and-singular-table-names/

Comment: @MortenMertner Yeah, I think he wants them plural, but I can't imagine why anyone would. If they do, they can just refer to them as the plural name! It's very disconcerning when you refer to a view and it tells you `Invalid object name 'dbo.viwReports'` when it's supposed to be `dbo.viwReport` and you want to use a model in your Data Context that is singular!!!!

Answer (score 12):

Open the `DbContext` class related to the tables you want to keep a singular table name.

If you are using EF 6, add a reference to:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
```

If it is an older version, add a reference to:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm.Db;
```

At last create a method that overrides the `OnModelCreating` and remove the convention to pluralize table names:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Remove "Pluralize or singularsize generated object names" check-mark when you create your entity object.

[image]

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the response.  this is literally my first MVC/EF project and im using the code-first approach.  I'm not entirely sure how to access the menu you posed a screenshot of.  Can you enlighten me?  thanks!

Comment: This method works if you add new entity object and point it to existing database schema.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Code First with EF 6.1 +, override the [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) event handler and make the following call(s):

```
dmbCloud.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
dmbCloud.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to override [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in your DbContext to specify the table name:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Vote>().MapSingleType().ToTable("Votes")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Vote is already being mapped to the 'Votes' table, but i implimented this just to see if it might connect some dots in the magic 'code-behind' of EF.  However, the the exception looking for mydb.vote is still being thrown.