# ADO.NET Entities 3.5 - Plural naming broken?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I'm building a data model using ADO.NET Entity Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

when I create the model from my database the object names are all plural rather than singular, for example, in my database I have a table called "Persons". ADO.NET calls the type name "Persons".

This contrasts with Linq-to-SQL where the designer/generator gives the entities singular names.

Annoyingly, if I rename each entity to its singular name ("Person") the designer renames their Entity Set Name to "PersonSet", so I have to rename that back to the plural.

Is this some configuration thing I've overlooked or is this somehow 'by design' in ADO.NET EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the third-party add-in Huagati DBML Tools: http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/ which performs pluralisation of entity names.

Answer (score 2):

There is a option "Pluralize or singularize generated object names" in the Ado.Net model creation wizard. Untick that option

[image]

Image taken from [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924806/60108)

Comment: I don't see that option in my Entity Data Model Wizard - I'm guessing this means the option is an EF4.0-only feature? I guess I'll have to write some macros to de-pluralise my entities.

Comment: That option is **NEW** in Entity Framework v4 - it was not available in the 3.5 version of Entity Framework