# Entity framework 'table-per-concrete-class' maps to wrong table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to do a table-per-concrete-class mapping with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC application. It's for a school assignement and i have to map to an existing (mysql) database.

```
public class Deelnemer
{
    public Deelnemer()
    {
        OpgelosteDoosVragen = new List<OpgelostDoosVraag>();
    }

    public string Emailadres { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OpgelostDoosVraag> OpgelosteDoosVragen { get; set; } 

    }
}
```

This class contains a list of 'OpgelosteDoosVragen'. The class 'OpgelosteDoosVragen' (empty at the moment) inherits from 'AbstractOpgelost'.

```
public abstract class AbstractOpgelost
{
    protected AbstractOpgelost()
    {
        OpgelostId = new Guid();
    }

    public Guid OpgelostId { get; set; }
    public virtual AbstractVraag AbstractVraag { get; set; }
    public virtual AbstractAntwoord AbstractAntwoord { get; set; }
    public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
}


public class OpgelostDoosVraag : AbstractOpgelost
{

}
```

The mapping:

```
public class AbstractOpgelostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<AbstractOpgelost>
{
    public AbstractOpgelostMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.OpgelostId);

        this.Property(t => t.OpgelostId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Element).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("elementNaam"));
        this.HasRequired(t => t.AbstractVraag).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("vraagId"));
        this.HasRequired(t => t.AbstractAntwoord).WithMany().Map(t => t.MapKey("antwoordId"));
    }
}

public class OpgelostDoosVraagMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<OpgelostDoosVraag>
{
    public OpgelostDoosVraagMap()
    {
        this.Map(t =>
            {
                t.MapInheritedProperties();
                t.ToTable("doos_opgelostevragen");
            });
    }
}
```

OnModelCreating method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {   
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OpgelostDoosVraagMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DeelnemerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new doosMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new doosVraagMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DoosAntwoordMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ElementMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AbstractAntwoordMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AbstractVraagMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AbstractOpgelostMap());

    }
```

When I try to access the list in Deelnemer an EntityCommandExecution is thrown is thrown and it says:
`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'kindermishandeling.abstractopgelosts' doesn't exist` 
The problem is entity framework wants to map to the table of the abstract class 'AbstractOpgelost' but it has to map to doos_opgelostevragen (the table of the concrete class).

Does anyone see a problem in my mapping. I'm looking for hours and i'm desperate...

Comment: Any chance you could add the contents of your `OnModelCreating()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in `public virtual IList<OpgelostDoosVraag> OpgelosteDoosVragen { get; set; }` . Because EF has a convention for the relationship like one to many. It will automatically understand this table in plural noun name, so that a reason because it threw the exception like that. Please go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta) and fix it

Please try to specify the table name for AbstractOpgelost class as well.

Could you avoid to make the abstraction for AbstractOpgelost class?

Comment: No, I don't know to which table AbstractOpgelost has to be mapped. The table depends on the concrete class (Table Per Concrete Class). And the naming convention has nothing to do with it. The table AbstractOpgelost also doesn't exist.