# Entity Framework mapped table name is wrong only in dbcontext object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have EF model gen from DB table . I can see that in model view, it is mapped to table Bargain. In DbContext class, there is def of DbSet:

```
public DbSet<bargain> bargains { get; set; }
```

I am using VS 2012. When I call:

```
db.bargains.Where(b => b.idBargain == 126216476).Select(b => b);
```

the generated SQL is using table name "Bargains", rather than "Bargain". Which bit is wrong?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta)

Comment: @markpsmith sorry page not found error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the link. To summarise, there are a couple of ways to override this default behaviour, assuming that's what you want.

Comment: You say that the model is correct but you didn't show us the model, which is almost certainly not correct. Show us the Bargain class.

Comment: @markpsmith is right. I switched off Plural setting and it is ok now.