# After Updating EF from database Name of my Context entities and model class has changed?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am working on application after updating it's EF from DB name changed giving many errors in application

Initially name in EF model `context.tt -> entities -> Agencies`

and in `Model.tt -> Agencies.cs`

After Updation it is like

Initially name in EF model `context.tt -> entities -> Agencies`

and `in Model.tt -> Agency.cs`

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You probably changed the pluralization settings while updating. You question doesn't give much info on what you did exactly.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta