# Table name created in EF, created into SQL with a different name

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I used EntityFramework with the Code First method to create the tables I need for my project. One of my tables is named "Forum" in c#, however when it created it in MSSQL it named it "Fora"...

All my tables generate exactly as I named them in c# except for the above case, I checked and "Forum" isn't a reserved keyword. And I was able to manually create a database and a table inside the new table named "Forum".

I scanned through the code of my entire project but I cannot find a reference to a "Fora".

Now from a coding perspective this isn't really an issue, I still access it within code as `dbContext.Forum.Get()`, however viewing the ERD shows it as Fora.

Has anyone else seen this happen before? Is there something specific I'm doing wrong?

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityProject.Utilities;

namespace CommunityProject.Data.Models
{
    public enum CanCreateTopic
    {
        Admin,
        Moderator,
        All
    }

    public partial class Forum : Entity
    {
        public Forum()
        {
            CanCreateTopicId = CanCreateTopic.All;
            IsDeleted = false;
            CDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            IsNewsForum = false;
        }

        [Index("IX_Forum_ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Foreign Keys

        [Index("IX_Forum_CategoryID")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int CUserId { get; set; }

        public int? EUserId { get; set; }

        //Content

        /// <summary>
        /// The icon to display on the forum
        /// </summary>
        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

        public CanCreateTopic CanCreateTopicId { get; set; }

        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If this is checked, the topics created here will be visible on the Home Page.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsNewsForum { get; set; }

        public DateTime CDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EDate { get; set; }

        //Virtuals

        public virtual User CreatedUser { get; set; }

        public virtual User EditedUser { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

        public bool UserCanCreateTopics(string forumUserType)
        {
            switch (CanCreateTopicId)
            {
                case CanCreateTopic.All:
                    return true;
                case CanCreateTopic.Moderator:
                    switch (forumUserType)
                    {
                        case AppConstants.AdministratorTypeName:
                        case AppConstants.ModeratorTypeName:
                        case AppConstants.OwnerTypeName:
                        case AppConstants.SystemTypeName:
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                case CanCreateTopic.Admin:
                    switch (forumUserType)
                    {
                        case AppConstants.AdministratorTypeName:
                        case AppConstants.OwnerTypeName:
                        case AppConstants.SystemTypeName:
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                default:
                    return false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Tables]

If you require more info, I'll update the question to add it :3

Comment: `Fora` is the plural of `Forum`, not `Forums`. Just like the plural for `index` is `indices`, not indexes. The convention for EF is to pluralize entity names. It also looks like the pluralization package used by EF works ... properly, so `Forum` became `Fora`

Comment: By default, EF will pluralize table names if they're not already plural. This can be overridden if so desired; globally in `OnModelCreating` and individually with the `Table` attribute. My preference for the plural form of the English word `Forum` would be `Forums` and not get clever with its Latin origins, but there you go.

Comment: Oh wow, that's bad. English isn't my first language, I thought it would be Forums :D Now I feel like a tool for not checking that first ._.

Comment: I've just checked the source code. Have a look here: 
https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Pluralization/EnglishPluralizationService.cs#L219

Comment: Both *forums* and *fora* are acceptable. EF apparently prefers *fora*, but for modern usage it's [in the minority](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forums%2Cfora&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cforums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfora%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

entity framework pluralizes the table names by default. 
Fora is the correct plural of Forum.

You can turn off the pluralization - the correct answer is found in the following question, also with discussion:

[Entity Framework creates a plural table name, but the view expects a singular table name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta)

The code snippet that does it is

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but you should not repeat or copy an answer from a duplicate question. Instead the question should be closed, as was done just now. Once you have enough reputation, you can participate in this process yourself.